# SSL for Lighttpd on different port Error 451 -

Tags: ssl, lighttpd

I'm not quite sure how to explain my problem but I'm going to try.

I have lighttpd 1.4.35 on Centos 6.4 64bit behind a firewall.  One of the virtual host is running using different port (8800) with SSL.  My setting is being done this way for the Vhost.

```
    $SERVER["socket"] == "192.168.1.200:8800" {
    ssl.engine  = "enable"
    ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/myssl/ca-certs.crt"
    ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/myssl/myssl.pem"
    server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
    server.document-root = "/var/www/lighttpd/myapps"
    }
```

Nothing really special actually and it works just fine until one of the page of the apps.  When I click on that page, it opens up the pop up window and all the pop up window shown is

```
    451 -
```

I'm not quite sure what it is.  I google what 451 - means and all the reference shown it has something to do with domain that posted some sort of illegal document.  WTH?  The apps is all internal apps that we created to serve internal people only.  which tells me that the error is not accurate.  However, when I access that virtual directory without the ssl,  that same page open just fine.

```
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "lab.myserver.net$" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/lighttpd/myapps"
    server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
    server.error-handler-404 = "/e404.php"
    }
```

I'm not quite sure what other additional info I need to post in here in order for you all to be able to see what potentially is the issue.

Here is part of the lighttpd.conf that I updated for the apps.

```
 url.rewrite-once = (
 ".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
 "^/js/.*$" => "$0",
 "^.*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf |jar|class)$" => "$0",
 "" => "/index.php"
 )
    include "vhosts.conf"
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with redirecting the page that ssl doesn't like but normally that only pertain to redirecting the apps to different server.  I'm attaching my fastcgi setup.

```
    fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
               ( "php-local" =>
                 (
                   "socket" => socket_dir + "/php-fastcgi-1.socket",
                   "max-procs" => 1,
                   "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable",
                 )
               ),
               ( "php-tcp" =>
                 (
                   "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                   "port" => 9999,
                   "check-local" => "disable",
                   "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable",
                 )
               ),

               ( "php-num-procs" =>
                 (
                   "socket" => socket_dir + "/php-fastcgi-2.socket",
                   "bin-environment" => (
                     "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "17",
                     "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000",
                   ),
                   "max-procs" => 5,
                   "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable",
                 )
               ),
            )
```

This apps are all calling the function in the same server.  Any suggestion on how to configure lighttpd with ssl using different port?  I think what I did is correct but it has always work in the past until I upgraded the server with different version of lighttpd.  Please help?

Comment: The 451 error is interesting.  What country are you in?  Are you using a linux distribution that may be restricted?  I know there are some encryption treaties that affect SSL but not sure if this is the case.   Most importantly, what is in your error log when you try to load the page?

Comment: Try using debug logs.